# iOS app crashing when clicking on a tab in tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am working on creating an iOS app for iPhone and I am running into a problem with the UITabBarController I am using. Whenever I click a tab that is in the tab bar, the program crashes. I am not using storyboard or anything of the sort and have opted to do everything through code. That being said, here is the code that sets up the tabs.

```
- (void) loadView
{
    // create main view
    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    self.view = contentView;

    // now create the tab pages
    StatusViewController *status = [[StatusViewController alloc] initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil];
    OperationsViewController *operations = [[OperationsViewController alloc] initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil];
    self.statusTab = status;
    self.operationsTab = operations;

    status.title = @"Status";
    operations.title = @"Operations";

    // create the tab bar controller and add all tabs
    UITabBarController *tabbar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabbar.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
    NSMutableArray *tabs = @[status, operations];
    [tabbar setViewControllers:tabs];
    [self.view addSubview: tabbar.view];
}
```

The tabs do show up correctly along the bottom of the app, and the content for the first tab is loaded correctly by default, by clicking any tab causes it to crash. When I do crash I am not getting a stack trace and XCode just higlights...

```
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MyAppDelegate class]));
}
```

Which is not very helpful (if somebody can comment how to get a stack tract in Xcode 5.1.1 I will be more than happy to update this post with additional information).

The classes that I have created, `StatusViewController` and `OperationsViewController` are both just subclasses of UIViewController where I added custom logic in `loadView`.

I saw other questions that seemed similar here on StackOverflow, but they were either using interfacebuilder/storyboard, or something else was different enough I felt the need to ask. Look forward to hearing any help anybody can offer me.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to add an exception breakpoint to see where exactly your app crashes. It's fairly easy to do so, but it helps a lot during debugging. Here's a tutorial http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions

Comment: Has `OperationsViewController` ever worked? Suspect `loadView` or `viewDidLoad` to have a problem.

Comment: @Wain Well it has worked in that if I make it the first tab to display the contents of it will load and then I am unable to get to the status tab.

Comment: @RinatKhanov I did go ahead and do that (thanks for the tip!) but it still seems to be highlighting the UIApplicationMain line for some reason...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to memory issues (often called a zombie). You aren't retaining the `UITabViewController`, so the views that should be managed by a `UITabViewController` are causing the crash.

When you use a view managed by another `UIViewController`, you can add them to the `childViewControllers` array of the parent `UIViewController`.

```
[self addChildViewController:tabBar];
[self.view addSubview: tabbar.view];
[tabBar didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Apple refers to this feature as "Custom Container View Controllers" https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

Comment: Well that fixed it. Thanks for the quick help!
This also ended up fixing some issues I was having inside the views that I was going to have to look into next. Nice!